# wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I am creating the wordpress theme and facing a little issue.

In my theme, there are pages, 
I want to show the title of the page like 'About', 'Blog'
how I can do this.

2nd I want to show the all the post just under the blog page. Even I created a template for blog, but unfortunelty, its not happening.

appreciate for ur help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a loop so wordpress can look and see if there is any content and if there is then display it

So page.php for your about page etc will be:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
<h1><?php the_title();?></h1><!--the title-->
<br />
<?php the_content();?><!--the content-->
<?php endwhile; endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1st: use `<?php the_title(); ?>` to display the pagetitle.

2nd: To display the full post, use: `<?php the_content(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
* Template Name: Blog
*/

  //to show title

    the_title();


  //to show the post

  if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

  the_content();<!--the content-->

  endwhile; endif;
```

Use the above code as per the requirement in the template page.

Comment: please try to format your answer properly: Code should be indented by 4 leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

**1. To show the title**

just add `<?php the_title(); ?>`

**2. To show the blog posts.**
I have written a bit of code to make show the all of blog posts in a page ,
im using query posts, lets make it :

```
    if (is_page($your_page_id)) { ?>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content">
    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; // for paging
    $args = array('paged' => $paged);
    query_posts($args); // query posts
    if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); // This code will display your posts
        endwhile;
        your_content_nav( 'nav-below' );
    endif;
    wp_reset_query(); // please, add this function to reset the query
    ?>         
    </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
    </div>
    } else {
 // normal page here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create blog and about pages. You must need to create the page through wordpress.
So click on your **wordpress** page `button` and then create you pages and set you `sub-menus` according to your mind ...

And for your second question, answer is go to latest page selection option and select static page for your **home/index/first** screen and then below page options select you menus where you want to move your latest post contents....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your posts in pages, you need to first create categories for your posts, then categorize each post. After that you can create your pages as per your post categories. Now for posting posts on those pages you can use the get_posts() method i posted in an answer [HERE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167740/posts-not-showing-on-page/216662#216662).